# Associated domains on iOS for custom domain

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, associated-domains

I'm thinking about how to setup associated domains for universal links and password autofill for our users. We currently have users on our own managed domains: `{username}.x.storage`, but they can also use their own custom domains such as `x.nl`.

I know that I could wildcard our own managed domain, but in Xcode, I need to fill in associated domains as well. So if a user has `x.nl` for domain, I don't want to list all custom domains in Xcode, that would be a huge hassle. What is the recommended approach?

Comment: What do you mean by users can use custom domains?  Are you talking about the users email addresses that they log in with or do you provide your app to clients that want to launch it from their own domain?

Comment: So, we offer users a default subdomain on our own product's domain, but they can also use their own registered domain from a web hosting company. So, the last option, they can buy x.nl and use it with our product by setting some DNS-settings I think.

Comment: The simplest approach is for them to redirect through your existing domain for universal links and for sign in. Otherwise you would need to keep releasing app updates with new domains